# buttons and text fields Properties

Tags: android-studio

I lost the properties interface of buttons and text fields on android studio 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm7RF.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Design tab is at the bottom left of the XML work area.
Switch to design view. Click "Design" tab at bottom-left work area.